# Removing folder from url where same website contains WordPress files and custom html files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website with both custom html and WordPress. It was developed by a previous developer. The WordPress installation is used only for blog contents. The folder level is as follows.

```
public_html
  -> index.html
  -> about.html
  -> html_folders
  -> wordpress
```

Everything is working fine. I have a page in WordPress which is

```
www.website.com/wordpress/contact-us/
```

I need it to say

```
www.website.com/contact-us
```

I did many Rewriterules in htaccess but still no luck. All I get is a 404 error. May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: "I have a website **with both custom html and WordPress**" - By "custom HTML" do you mean separate HTML files outside of WordPress? How are you referencing these URLs? Complete filename + extension? Please include the contents of your existing `.htaccess` file, what you have tried and where in the `.htaccess` file you added these directives.